# MYSQL DB not starting

Tags: mysql, vps

I have VPS where I run apache and mysql and since yesterday I can't launch the mysql server anymore:

```
sudo service mysql start
start: Job failed to start
```

output of error.log at `/var/log/mysql/error.log`:

```
2015-10-31 01:20:37 9857 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
2015-10-31 01:20:37 9857 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-10-31 01:20:37 9857 [ERROR] Function 'innodb' already exists
2015-10-31 01:20:37 9857 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'innodb' with soname 'ha_innodb.so'.
2015-10-31 01:20:37 9857 [ERROR] Function 'federated' already exists
2015-10-31 01:20:37 9857 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'federated' with soname 'ha_federated.so'.
2015-10-31 01:20:37 9857 [ERROR] Function 'blackhole' already exists
2015-10-31 01:20:37 9857 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'blackhole' with soname 'ha_blackhole.so'.
2015-10-31 01:20:37 9857 [ERROR] Function 'archive' already exists
2015-10-31 01:20:37 9857 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'archive' with soname 'ha_archive.so'.
2015-10-31 01:20:37 9857 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-10-31 01:20:37 9857 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-10-31 01:20:37 9857 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2015-10-31 01:20:37 9857 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-10-31 01:20:37 9857 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2015-10-31 01:20:37 9857 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2015-10-31 01:20:37 9857 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-10-31 01:20:37 9857 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2015-10-31 01:20:37 9857 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-10-31 01:20:37 9857 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-10-31 01:20:37 9857 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 2997681 and 2997681 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 2997691 in the ib_logfiles!
2015-10-31 01:20:37 9857 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2015-10-31 01:20:37 9857 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2015-10-31 01:20:37 9857 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2015-10-31 01:20:37 9857 [ERROR] InnoDB: Tried to read 16384 bytes at offset 0. Was only able to read 0.
2015-10-31 01:20:37 7f082bec7780  InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create
InnoDB: directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
2015-10-31 01:20:37 9857 [ERROR] InnoDB: File (unknown): 'read' returned OS error 71. Cannot continue operation
2015-10-31 01:20:39 9899 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
2015-10-31 01:20:39 9899 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-10-31 01:20:39 9899 [ERROR] Function 'innodb' already exists
2015-10-31 01:20:39 9899 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'innodb' with soname 'ha_innodb.so'.
2015-10-31 01:20:39 9899 [ERROR] Function 'federated' already exists
2015-10-31 01:20:39 9899 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'federated' with soname 'ha_federated.so'.
2015-10-31 01:20:39 9899 [ERROR] Function 'blackhole' already exists
2015-10-31 01:20:39 9899 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'blackhole' with soname 'ha_blackhole.so'.
2015-10-31 01:20:39 9899 [ERROR] Function 'archive' already exists
2015-10-31 01:20:39 9899 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'archive' with soname 'ha_archive.so'.
2015-10-31 01:20:39 9899 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-10-31 01:20:39 9899 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-10-31 01:20:39 9899 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2015-10-31 01:20:39 9899 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-10-31 01:20:39 9899 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2015-10-31 01:20:39 9899 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2015-10-31 01:20:39 9899 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-10-31 01:20:39 9899 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2015-10-31 01:20:39 9899 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-10-31 01:20:39 9899 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-10-31 01:20:39 9899 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 2997681 and 2997681 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 2997691 in the ib_logfiles!
2015-10-31 01:20:39 9899 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2015-10-31 01:20:39 9899 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2015-10-31 01:20:39 9899 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2015-10-31 01:20:39 9899 [ERROR] InnoDB: Tried to read 16384 bytes at offset 0. Was only able to read 0.
2015-10-31 01:20:39 7f6cada08780  InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create
InnoDB: directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
2015-10-31 01:20:39 9899 [ERROR] InnoDB: File (unknown): 'read' returned OS error 71. Cannot continue operation
2015-10-31 01:20:40 9941 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use the full name instead.
2015-10-31 01:20:40 9941 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-10-31 01:20:40 9941 [ERROR] Function 'innodb' already exists
2015-10-31 01:20:40 9941 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'innodb' with soname 'ha_innodb.so'.
2015-10-31 01:20:40 9941 [ERROR] Function 'federated' already exists
2015-10-31 01:20:40 9941 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'federated' with soname 'ha_federated.so'.
2015-10-31 01:20:40 9941 [ERROR] Function 'blackhole' already exists
2015-10-31 01:20:40 9941 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'blackhole' with soname 'ha_blackhole.so'.
2015-10-31 01:20:40 9941 [ERROR] Function 'archive' already exists
2015-10-31 01:20:40 9941 [Warning] Couldn't load plugin named 'archive' with soname 'ha_archive.so'.
2015-10-31 01:20:40 9941 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-10-31 01:20:40 9941 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-10-31 01:20:40 9941 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2015-10-31 01:20:40 9941 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-10-31 01:20:40 9941 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2015-10-31 01:20:40 9941 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2015-10-31 01:20:40 9941 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-10-31 01:20:40 9941 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2015-10-31 01:20:40 9941 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-10-31 01:20:40 9941 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-10-31 01:20:40 9941 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 2997681 and 2997681 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 2997691 in the ib_logfiles!
2015-10-31 01:20:40 9941 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2015-10-31 01:20:40 9941 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2015-10-31 01:20:40 9941 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2015-10-31 01:20:40 9941 [ERROR] InnoDB: Tried to read 16384 bytes at offset 0. Was only able to read 0.
2015-10-31 01:20:40 7f3b70b2e780  InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create
InnoDB: directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
2015-10-31 01:20:40 9941 [ERROR] InnoDB: File (unknown): 'read' returned OS error 71. Cannot continue operation`2015-10-31 01:20:37 9857
[Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. 
Please use the full name instead.
```

Questions is, how do I get it back up and running? I haven't changed much except for apt-get upgrade.

edit:

Databases at /var/lib/mysql/mysql:

`columns_priv.MYD   innodb_index_stats.frm    slave_worker_info.ibd
    columns_priv.MYI   innodb_index_stats.ibd    slow_log.CSM
    columns_priv.frm   innodb_table_stats.frm    slow_log.CSV
    db.MYD             innodb_table_stats.ibd    slow_log.frm
    db.MYI             ndb_binlog_index.MYD      tables_priv.MYD
    db.frm             ndb_binlog_index.MYI      tables_priv.MYI
    event.MYD          ndb_binlog_index.frm      tables_priv.frm
    event.MYI          plugin.MYD                time_zone.MYD
    event.frm          plugin.MYI                time_zone.MYI
    func.MYD           plugin.frm                time_zone.frm
    func.MYI           proc.MYD                  time_zone_leap_second.MYD
    func.frm           proc.MYI                  time_zone_leap_second.MYI
    general_log.CSM    proc.frm                  time_zone_leap_second.frm
    general_log.CSV    procs_priv.MYD            time_zone_name.MYD
    general_log.frm    procs_priv.MYI            time_zone_name.MYI
    help_category.MYD  procs_priv.frm            time_zone_name.frm
    help_category.MYI  proxies_priv.MYD          time_zone_transition.MYD
    help_category.frm  proxies_priv.MYI          time_zone_transition.MYI
    help_keyword.MYD   proxies_priv.frm          time_zone_transition.frm
    help_keyword.MYI   servers.MYD               time_zone_transition_type.MYD
    help_keyword.frm   servers.MYI               time_zone_transition_type.MYI
    help_relation.MYD  servers.frm               time_zone_transition_type.frm
    help_relation.MYI  slave_master_info.frm     user.MYD
    help_relation.frm  slave_master_info.ibd     user.MYI
    help_topic.MYD     slave_relay_log_info.frm  user.frm
    help_topic.MYI     slave_relay_log_info.ibd
    help_topic.frm     slave_worker_info.frm`

Comment: is you HDD in good condition ? it seems InnoDB engine can't read your database files.

Comment: Perhaps stating the obvious, but did you check the database files are actually there? According to the error, they are not, or at least, cannot be accessed.

Comment: @pat As it is a VPS in a Datacenter, i can't really check that.
@ JayMcTee i added the DBs in /var/lib/mysql

Comment: Nobody? Problem still exits...

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but is your disk full?

Comment: No stupid questions, only stupid answers! But no, disk is only half full, leaving around 25GB empty space!